# Saving current time as a variable and continuing count from that value

Tags: java, debugging, time, save

I am making a stopwatch and struggling to make the stop function work properly.

When I stop the timer at 7 seconds and restart, it goes back down to 0 second and starts over; however, I want it to start at 7 seconds. Sometimes, the stopwatch breaks and keeps showing 1.529679177849E9 seconds.

I know that I need to store the saved time in a variable, but I don't know how.

Can you help me solve this problem?

```
public class stopwatch {
    public long thetime = 0;
    public long stoppedtime = 0;
    public boolean ticking = false;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        stopwatch s = new stopwatch();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean loop = true;
        while (loop = true) {
            System.out.println("1 start 2 is started 3 stop 4 "
                    + "reset 5 check time 6 stop");
            int i = sc.nextInt();
            if (i == 1) {
                s.start();
            } else if (i == 2) {
                System.out.println(s.isStarted());
            } else if (i == 3) {
                s.stop();
            } else if (i == 4) {
                s.reset();
            } else if (i == 5) {
                System.out.println("saved time is " + s.time() + " Seconds");
            } else if (i == 6) {
                System.out.println("closing");
                loop = false;
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("invalid");
            }

        }

    }

    public void start() {

        if (ticking == true) {
            thetime = thetime;
        } else {
            thetime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            ticking = true;
        }
    }

    public boolean isStarted() {
        return ticking;
    }

    public void stop() {
        if (ticking == false) {
            stoppedtime = stoppedtime;
        } else {
            stoppedtime = thetime;
            ticking = false;
        }
    }


    public void reset() {
        thetime = 0;
        stoppedtime = 0;
    }

    public double time() {
        double seconds = 1000.000000;
        double currenttime = 0;
        double saved = stoppedtime;
        if (ticking == true) {
            currenttime = ((System.currentTimeMillis() - thetime) / seconds);
            return currenttime;


        } else {
            currenttime = (stoppedtime / seconds);
            return currenttime;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you search for similar questions? There are some.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issue which I have fixed, please find the working code below:

1) stoppedtime was not converting into seconds while returning time

2) Just add stopped time in actual result to ensure it always get added till the time the reset is called

3) As per coding standards, class name should always start with capital letter

```
public class Stopwatch {
public long thetime = 0;
public long stoppedtime = 0;
public boolean ticking = false;
public int laps = 0;
public long lastTime = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean loop = true;
    while (loop = true) {
        System.out.println("1 start 2 is started 3 stop 4 " + "reset 5 check time 6 stop");
        int i = sc.nextInt();
        if (i == 1) {
            s.start();
        } else if (i == 2) {
            System.out.println(s.isStarted());
        } else if (i == 3) {
            s.stop();
        } else if (i == 4) {
            s.reset();
        } else if (i == 5) {
            System.out.println("saved time is " + s.time() + " Seconds");
        } else if (i == 6) {
            System.out.println("closing");
            loop = false;
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("invalid");
        }

    }

}

public void start() {

    if (!ticking) {
        thetime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        ticking = true;
    }
}

public boolean isStarted() {
    return ticking;
}

public void stop() {
    if (ticking ) {
        stoppedtime += (System.currentTimeMillis() - thetime);
        ticking = false;
    }
}

public void reset() {
    thetime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    stoppedtime = 0;
}

public double time() {
    double seconds = 1000.000000;
    double currenttime = 0;
    if (ticking) {
        currenttime = (stoppedtime + System.currentTimeMillis() - thetime) / seconds;
        return currenttime;

    } else {
        currenttime = (stoppedtime / seconds);
        return currenttime;
    }

   }
 }
```

Output:

```
1 start 2 is started 3 stop 4 reset 5 check time 6 stop
5
saved time is 0.0 Seconds <-- Starting time to be zero
1 start 2 is started 3 stop 4 reset 5 check time 6 stop
1 <-- Start time
1 start 2 is started 3 stop 4 reset 5 check time 6 stop
3 <-- Stop Time
1 start 2 is started 3 stop 4 reset 5 check time 6 stop
5
saved time is 1.304 Seconds <-- Time of stopwatch
1 start 2 is started 3 stop 4 reset 5 check time 6 stop
1 <- Started time from 1.304 Seconds
1 start 2 is started 3 stop 4 reset 5 check time 6 stop
5
saved time is 1.788 Seconds <- After immediately checking time post start as you can see timer started from previous recorded time
1 start 2 is started 3 stop 4 reset 5 check time 6 stop
3 <- Stop time
1 start 2 is started 3 stop 4 reset 5 check time 6 stop
5
saved time is 4.988 Seconds <--Combined time for Lap 1 + Lap 2
1 start 2 is started 3 stop 4 reset 5 check time 6 stop
4 <- Reset time
1 start 2 is started 3 stop 4 reset 5 check time 6 stop
5
saved time is 0.0 Seconds <- Time reset to 0 Seconds
1 start 2 is started 3 stop 4 reset 5 check time 6 stop
1 <- Start time
1 start 2 is started 3 stop 4 reset 5 check time 6 stop
3 <- Stop  time
1 start 2 is started 3 stop 4 reset 5 check time 6 stop
5
saved time is 0.796 Seconds <- Previous lap time not recorded as reset was done
```

Comment: Well I appreciate for trying to help but these changes didn't really change much how the code functions.

Comment: @j.doe it is as per your requirement. Please check the output above where recorded times are getting added if you start and stop multiple times, but if you reset the time, it will again change the start time to zero.

Comment: Tested your code again and I noticed it works kinda, but there is an issue if you reset the timer without stopping first then the saved time is permantly stored as 1.529749753663E9 Seconds. Other than that it seems to be working.

Comment: @j.doe to fix that just call stop from reset as first line

Comment: @j.doe There is another option to fix this issue, just change thetime = 0 to thetime = System.currentTimeMillis(); in reset function. I have updated my answer as well.

Comment: Changin to System.currentTimeMillis(); many thanks didn't know why it never crossed my mind. Many thanks,

Comment: Both ways are so simple I can't believe it never crossed my mind I was putting more if statements in the time method, many thanks hope you have a great weekend.